# Time Efficient Frequency Count (top 500 words) of a Large Directory in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, nltk, tokenize, wordnet, word-frequency

I wish to calculate the top 500 words (in terms of occurrence) for all the files (a maximum of 15,000 files) of a directory. I am experimenting the same on small sized directories containing  1000 files. For these 1000 files, I am getting results, but time efficiency is not preserved. It takes too much time to process.

Firstly, I have merged all the files into a single file, namely `combined.txt`, which is the input file (using [TXTcollector](https://bluefive.pairsite.com/txtcollector.htm)). Then I have pre-processed (stopwords, lowercase and lemmas and pos tagging) it and computed the top 500 words with the help of `nltk` `FreqDist()`.

Combined.txt is the input file and it contains data's from multiple text files separated by ==== (delimiter).

At present, my code is very slow in terms of performance. This is because For a 36 Kb file (combining all the files of a directory) : the below mentioned code takes 4.6 sec and for 8888 MB file (combining all the files of a directory) it's taking 672 sec to process. And further, when the size will get increased, then the code will be in-efficient in terms of time, also same happens, if the size of the file in the directory escalates.

Note: I am using Windows 10, 64 bit, Python 3.7 and my editor is Sublime-text. I have computed the elapsed time, from the editor itself.

The code is as follows:

```
import nltk
from nltk.stem.wordnet import WordNetLemmatizer
from nltk.tokenize.regexp import wordpunct_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.data import load
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize, RegexpTokenizer

_POS_TAGGER = 'taggers/maxent_treebank_pos_tagger/english.pickle'
tagger = load(_POS_TAGGER)
regexp_tagger = nltk.tag.RegexpTagger([(r'\(|\)', '--')], backoff = tagger) 

def read_data():
    with open("path", 'r', encoding='utf-8', errors = 'replace') as f:
        raw_data = f.read()
        global text
        text = '\n'.join(nltk.line_tokenize(raw_data.lower()))
read_data()

def preprocess():
    stop_words = set(stopwords.words("english"))
    tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
    pos_text = regexp_tagger.tag(tokens)
    names = [n.encode('utf-8') for n,pos in pos_text if (pos == 'NN' or pos == 'NNP' or pos == 'NNS' or pos == 'NNPS')]
    names_text = (' '.join(map(bytes.decode, names))).strip()
    tokens = [t for t in wordpunct_tokenize(names_text)]
    tokens = filter(lambda x: x not in stop_words, tokens)
    tokens = filter(lambda x: x.isalpha(), tokens)
    tokens = filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1, tokens)
    wordnet_lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
    global lemmatized_tokens
    lemmatized_tokens = [wordnet_lemmatizer.lemmatize(t) for t in tokens]

preprocess()


def freq_count():
    fd = nltk.FreqDist(lemmatized_tokens)
    print(fd.most_common(500))
freq_count()
```

How to achieve efficient results in terms of time?

Comment: A list constructor `list(something)` should be slightly faster than comprehension `[t for t in something]`, but if you run `preprocess()` only once, the difference will probably be small.

Comment: You should measure execution time of the individual steps in the process, e.g. how long `freq_count()` itself takes. I made a tuple of 5 million words. Counting with `collections.Counter()` took 1.3 seconds.